# Absolute value, the way of solving

Tags: absolute-value

$$0>1,4 -\mid2,6-x\mid$$
Have i done it in good way ??
$$-\mid2,6-x\mid<-1,4$$
$$(-\mid2,6-x\mid<-1,4)*(-1)$$
$$\mid2,6-x\mid>1,4$$

Now we've got 2 possibilities
$$2,6-x>1,4$$
and
$$2,6-x>-1,4$$

THE RESULTS:
$$x < 1,2$$
$$x < 4$$

Comment: Sometimes it helps to read the expression form out loud. $|2.6-x|>1.4$ reads: "The distance from $x$ to $2.6$ is greater then $1.4$."

Answer (score 1):

Your one fault is that the your second "possibility" is wrong.

It should be

$$2.6-x < -1.4$$

An easy way to think about it is that you need the LHS to be "more" negative than $-1.4$, because that will make its absolute value bigger than $1.4$

When working with multiplying/dividing negatives as well as working with absolute values, you're gonna need to grow comfortable with switching the inequality sign and knowing when to do so.

Final answer should be

$$x < 1.2$$
$$x > 4$$

Comment: [This](https://www.purplemath.com/modules/absineq.htm) website does a good job of explaining absolute value inequalities.

Comment: Even though the OP did it, you should not leave the final answer without a logical connector.

Answer (score 0):

$$|2.6-x|>1.4$$ is

$$2.6-x>1.4\text{ or }x-2.6>1.4$$

which is

$$x<1.2\text{ or }x>4.$$